# Initialize random number generator in ruby (i.e. set seed)?

Tags: ruby, random-seed

How can we set a seed in ruby such that any functions dependent on RNG return the same results (e.g. similar to python's [random.seed()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) ?

Answer (score 8):

To set the global random seed, you can use [`Kernel#srand`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-srand). This will affect future calls to `Kernel#rand`, the global random number function.

```
srand(some_number)
rand() # Should get consistent results here
```

If you want local randomness without affecting the global state, then you want to use the [`Random`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Random.html) class. The constructor of this class takes a random seed.

```
r = Random.new(some_number)
r.rand() # Should get same result as above
```

Generally, it can be helpful to pass around specific random states, as it makes mocking and testing much easier and keeps your function effects local.

Comment: Could you please explain this in a little more detail in the answer: *Generally, it can be helpful to pass around specific random states, as it makes mocking and testing much easier and keeps your function effects local.*?

Comment: This should be the preferred answer - big +1 for mentioning the side-effects of `srand`

Answer (score 4):

Use the `srand()` method

```
srand(12345)

rand() 
=> 0.9296160928171479
rand()
=> 0.3163755545817859

srand(12345)

rand() 
=> 0.9296160928171479
rand()
=> 0.3163755545817859
```